# If statements for Checkboxes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, if-statement, checkbox

I wanted to know how to write if statements to see if one or another check box is checked or not.

I have two check boxes.  I wanted it to check to see if checkbox 1 is checked and checkbox 2 is null then call this function, and if checkbox 2 is checked and checkbox 1 is null then call another function.

Pretty bad with IF statements and not sure how to convert the checkbox into a readable value.

Comment: Could you add the code as it looks right now?

Comment: Do you truly intend `null`, or were you thinking of `false`? A checkbox can have 3 states, one of which can be `null`.

Comment: I am not sure.  What are the three states?  I thought there could only be two.  So by null I was implying not checked.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I'm making an assumption that you mean not checked. I don't have a C# compiler handy but:

```
if (checkbox1.Checked && !checkbox2.Checked)
{

}
else if (!checkbox1.Checked && checkbox2.Checked)
{

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're going to use the `checkbox1.checked` property in your if statement.

This returns true or false, depending on whether it is checked or not.

Answer (score 2):

I simplification for Science_Fiction's answer I think is to use the exclusive or function so you can just have:

```
if(checkbox1.checked ^ checkbox2.checked)
{
//do stuff
}
```

That is assuming you want to do the same thing for both situations.

Answer (score 1):

In VB.Net

```
If Check1.checked and Not (Check2.checked) Then

ElseIf Check2.Checked and not Check1.Checked then

End If
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBoxImage.Checked)
    {
        groupBoxImage.Show();
    }
    else if (!checkBoxImage.Checked)
    {
        groupBoxImage.Hide(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest

```
if (checkbox.IsChecked == true)
{
    //do something
}
```

Hope it's helpful ^^

Comment: This will result in a compilation error, as `IsChecked` isn't a property on a CheckBox. You also don't need to include a `== true` check against a Boolean in C#.