# Check checkbox in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, checkbox

How can I check whether the checkbox is checked or not in ASP.NET?

Default.aspx

```
<div class="check_all">
 <label class="container">
   Web Design
   <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox" runat="server"/>
   <span class="checkmark"></span>
 </label>
 <label class="container">
   Web Development
   <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"/>
   <span class="checkmark"></span>
 </label>
 <label class="container">
   App Design
   <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
   <span class="checkmark"></span>
 </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean check in your code behind file (.aspx.cs) or in the page itself (.aspx)?

Comment: In the code behind (.aspx.cs)

Comment: @SBFrancies code behind (aspx.cs)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If statements for Checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849930/if-statements-for-checkboxes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Checked` property of the `CheckBox` control. See [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checked(v=vs.110).aspx) for the documentation with code examples.